# Error when assigning array by using Split on range value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to parse a string from a cell to an array to separate the data and put it into another worksheet.

I keep getting the ***Can't assign to array*** error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I made sure the data types were correct and even made sure there was enough room on the array.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Enter2_Click()
'Define Variables
Dim MatchRow As Integer
Dim data(7) As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim dataInfo As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Match Name To A Row
MatchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(RName.Value, Range("A1:A100"), 0)
MsgBox MatchRow
'call report
Cells(MatchRow, 3).Select
data() = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".", 1) 'This is where the error comes from
MsgBox data(0)
Worksheets("Repoting template").Cells(20, 1).Select
```

Comment: u have to declare it as variant, and no need to specify the dimension since u are using `split` i.e. `dim data as variant`, then `data = split(activecell.value,".")`

Comment: Now it says type mismatch.

Comment: limit as long is default to `-1`, it is `-1` but not `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:
`data() = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".", 1)`

to this:
`data() = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".")`

Example:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. After changing the type back to string for the array and taking the 1 out it worked!

Comment: I prefer `Debug.Print Join(Data, VbCrLf)` or `Debug.Print Join(Data, ",")`

Answer (score 3):

If you have sample data like this:

[image]

You can try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim data() As String

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    data = Split(rng.Value, ".", -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        Debug.Print data(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Which gives the following output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

Comment: Comprehensive solution for more control, but you can also fill the array without iterating over it if you don't need this kind of control :)

Comment: @Vegard - the code fills the array with the `Split` function. The iteration is simply to produce a debug to show that `Split` worked :) Our answers are essentially the same

Comment: Oh, indeed... I read too fast, I thought the iteration was to fill the array, per how MSDN shows it.